# Transifex missing a string about incorrect e-mail

Tags: bug, status-review, login, email, localization

When I try to login in ruSO but put in an incorrect e-mail address, I get the string "No user found with matching email", untranslated. I wrote a bug-report [in ruSO meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13043/532877), but a [moderator said](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13043/#comment56332_13043), that in transifex there isn't such a string.

And it is interesting: Why is this string repeated three times? Is this for the user to better understand ?

[image: Attempting to login to Russian Stack Overflow, the message "No user found with matching email" is displayed (in English) three times]